# React router in typescript giving errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

My requirement was simple. Just wanted to introduce the React router in a existing React application written in typescript.

I installed react-router using below commands:

`npm install react-router-dom @types/react-router-dom`

Used in my App.js as below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from './routes';

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/CompanyDirectory">CompanyDirectory</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr />
                    <Routes />
                </div>
            </Router>

        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Routes.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import CompanyDirectory from './CompanyDirectory/CompanyDirectory';
import Home from './Home/Home';

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/CompanyDirectory' component={() => <CompanyDirectory />} />
            <Route exact path='/' component={() => <Home />} />
        </Switch>
    )
}

export default Routes;
```

When I try to compile my code and execute using `gulp serve --nobrowser`
I get below errors.

```
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(94,33): error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(95,11): error TS1109: Expression expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(96,15): error TS1109: Expression expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(97,12): error TS1109: Expression expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(98,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(146,100): error TS1110: Type expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(146,109): error TS1005: '}' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(146,114): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(146,115): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(152,18): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(152,19): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(152,26): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(152,33): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(152,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(152,42): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(152,49): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(153,43): error TS1005: '(' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(154,5): error TS1005: '(' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(154,9): error TS1005: ',' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(154,26): error TS1005: '}' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(154,32): error TS1005: ',' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(154,33): error TS1135: Argument expression expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(154,35): error TS1005: ',' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(154,42): error TS1005: ':' expected.
[16:49:52] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(188,1): error TS1160: Unterminated template literal.
```

MY package.json is has :

```
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"devDependencies": {
   "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
   "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
   "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
   "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
   "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
   "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-2.9": "0.7.7",
   "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.8.2",
   "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.8.2",
   "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.8.2",
   "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.8.2",
   "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
   "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
   "@types/react": "^16.7.22",
   "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.0",
   "ajv": "~5.2.2",
   "gulp": "~3.9.1"
 }
}
```

Someone, please help me in understanding the issue here. Am I doing something wrong?
The typescript version reflected in package-lock.json is:
 `"typescript": "~2.9.2"`

Kindly Help! Thanks.

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
  "extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-2.9/includes/tsconfig-web.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "inlineSources": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@microsoft"
    ],
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom",
      "es2015.collection"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
, "src/<Project>/components/routes.ts" , "src/<Project>/components/App.tsx" ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "lib"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try renaming the files from .js to .tsx ?

Comment: Yes I renamed the files but still the same errors as above. Can you please help. Tried a number of things but not able to figure out the issue

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be sure to only use `.tsx` as file extension for Typescript files and be sure to import React on top of your files (in case thats missing)

Also try to pass your Component directly into the Routes `component`-property.

For example:
`<Route exact path='/CompanyDirectory' component={CompanyDirectory} />`

In case this doesn't help, please provide some informations about the tsconfig you are using. as well as your `@types/react-router-dom` version, because it is not visible in your package.json snipped.

Comment: When I change the file extension from .tsx to .ts . I start getting errors in my file. What is the difference between them . Can you please explain when we use either of these extensions

Comment: Oh sorry, i meant `.tsx` not `.ts`. In your original question you are naming the files with `.js` fileextensions

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import React in `Routes.js` and `App.js`
if the problem still happen tell me

Comment: I have imported in routes.tsx and App.tsx:``` import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import CompanyDirectory from './CompanyDirectory/CompanyDirectory';
import Home from './Home/Home';

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/CompanyDirectory' component={() => <CompanyDirectory />} />
            <Route exact path='/' component={() => <Home />} />
        </Switch>
    )
}

export default Routes;``` May be that line did not got pasted in the snippet above